# Ruby gsub regex unexpected behaviour

Tags: ruby, regex

I thought I knew regexes pretty well, but this has me puzzled:

```
irb(main):016:0> source = "/foo/bar"
=> "/foo/bar"
irb(main):017:0> source.gsub( /[^\/]*\Z/, "fubar" )
=> "/foo/fubarfubar"
```

As far as I can tell, `/[^\/]*\Z/` has a unique expansion to match `bar` and therefore should result in `/foo/fubar`. I can't see at all why I get `fubarfubar` as the replacement.

The replacement works if I call `sub` rather than `gsub`, so it's not a question of working around the problem but rather uncovering my misunderstanding of `gsub`.

Comment: p source.gsub( /[^\/]+\Z/, "fubar" )

Comment: Was able to reproduce as well. Seems like a bug if you ask me: `/[^\/]*\Z/.match(source).to_a => ["bar"]`

Comment: @Josh, in 1,342 SO questions where a bug was suspected, it was indeed a bug twice. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Oh absolutely. I'm not saying I'm right, just that I wouldn't expect that either. I'm sure there's probably good reason for the behavior. Or not ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `sub` as you only need to replace once at the end of the string:

```
source.sub( /[^\/]*\Z/, "fubar" )
       ^^^
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/tnw7W9)

The problem is most probably with the way the matches are collected, and since you pattern matches an empty string, although at the end, the last *null* can also be treated as a 2nd match. It is not only a Ruby issue, a similar bug is present in many other languages.

So, actually, this is what is happening:

- `[^\/]*\Z` pattern matches `bar` and replaces it with `foobar`
- Regex index is at the end of the string - yes, there is a NULL, but Ruby still sees it as a valid "string" to process and
- `[^\/]*\Z` matches the NULL, and adds another `foobar`.

If you need to use `gsub`, replace `*` quantifier that allows matching 0 characters with `+` that requires at least 1 occurrence of the quantified subpattern, avoid matching 0-length strings:

```
source.gsub( /[^\/]+\Z/, "fubar" )
                   ^
```

***The rule of thumb*: Avoid regexps that match empty strings inside Regex replace methods!**

Comment: The question isn't how to fix the problem (I mentioned `sub` in my post), but *why* `gsub` fails in this case. `*` is a greedy operator, so there should only be one expansion

Comment: Avoid regexps inside regex replace methods that match empty strings - that is the rule of a thumb. The problem is internal, connected with how the regex engine deals with zero-length matches while collecting them for replacement.

Comment: I added the 3-step description of what is really going on.

Comment: I can see that using `+` instead of `*` fixes the symptom, but I still don't quite see what's happening since: 
`irb(main):003:0> source.match( /[^\/]+\Z/ ).size
=> 1
`

Comment: @IanDickinson: There may be difference in how `match` and `gsub` work, BTW, this is not a valid basis for comparison. However, the pattern with `+` should correctly match 1 `bar` at the end once, true. The point is: why use a regex that can match an empty string to replace something?

Comment: Good answer, but I wonder if your "rule of thumb" isn't a little strong. I am in particular thinking of matching an empty string that is adjacent to a lookaround, which can be quite useful. A belated congratulations on hitting the century mark for rep.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Thank you. I do strongly believe that replacing an empty string with a non-empty string is in 99.9% cases a user error. If you need to remove all non-`/` symbols before the end of string, match at least once, why add redundant overhead?

Comment: @IanDickinson note that `match` only returns the first match. `source.scan(/[^\/]*\Z/)` reveals that there are in fact two matches: `["bar", ""]`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a bug at all. Regular expressions can and will match zero-width positions.

Therefore, the regex engine sees the string `"xox"` more like this:

```
"" "x" "" "o" "" "x" ""
```

(fun fact: in Ruby, the above actually results in `"xox"`)

If we `gsub` a single `x` with a `_`, everything works as expected:

```
"xox".gsub(/x/, "_") #=> "_o_"
```

But if we match `x*`, things get weird:

```
"xox".gsub(/x*/, "_") #=> "__o__"
```

This is because `*` matches *zero* or more times:

```
"" "x" "" "o" "" "x" ""
^^^^^^ ^^     ^^^^^^ ^^
```

It may be clearer if we reduce "zero or more" to just zero:

```
"xox".gsub(/x{0}/, "_") #=> "_x_o_x_"
```

The matches are:

```
"" "x" "" "o" "" "x" ""
^^     ^^     ^^     ^^
```

The same happens in your example. You match `[^\/]` zero or more times. The regex engine matches `bar` at the end of the string (`[^\/]` 3 times) and the void afterwards (`[^\/]` 0 times):

```
"/" "" "b" "" "a" "" "r" ""
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^
```